# How to connect to web2py server remotely

Tags: web-applications, server, connection, web2py, web2py-modules

I have set up a web2py application on my ubuntu 12.04 system. On the machine, the application gets opened in browser via localhost:8000. But when I try to connect through other computer, its not connecting.

I tried to connect via IP address of the server. I found the ip address using ifconfig.The on other system I tried using IP:8000/application/ but it does not connect. I tried with/without port also.

Anyone has any idea? Why I am not able to connect to web2py application
remotely? Or am I missing something?

You help will be highly appreciated. I am really stuck.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are running web2py via the development server with its default settings, which means web2py will only be accessible from the local machine (that is the meaning of "localhost"). If you want to access the web application from beyond your local network, you should specify the IP address via the command line:

```
python web2py.py -i 0.0.0.0 -p 80 -a your_admin_password
```

Note, the above also sets the port to 80 so you won't have to bother including a port in the URL.

Also, keep in mind that the built-in server is intended primarily for development purposes. In most cases, for a production application, you should use a production quality web server. See the chapter on [deployment](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13/deployment-recipes).